# does hadoop 2.8 support apache spark cluster 2.1?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing

Could you please let me know that is Apache Hadoop 2.8 is compatible with Apache spark 2.1.1 or not?
I have already set up a test cluster where Apache Hadoop 2.8 is installed , and now we need apache spark 2.1.1 to be installed on the top of that.
If yes , then please let us know that which package will be good to install? (Please provide the URL here).

Comment: please check [this](https://github.com/zipfian/spark-install) . everything should be same except the versions of spark, scala and hadoop.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thanks for your reply. Somehow I ended up installing hadoop 2.6 with spark 1.6. Now everything is working fine but Datanode of Hadoop is not starting anyhow. Is there any work around?

Comment: If its working with spark 1.6 then it should be same for spark 2.1.1 as well. Just follow the same way. Did you encounter any problems? If yes let us work together to sort them out.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes , it worked in 2.1.1 also. But there I have faced the same problem that is DataNode for Hadoop was not working. I have done few troubleshoting steps but alas! , Do you want to see the config files of Hadoop? like hdfs-site.xml , core-site.xml and all?

Comment: did you check for the logs of datanode? What I am confused is that if its working for 1.6 then why not for 2.1.1?

Comment: Yes , I checked about the logs. and its saying as below. and yes the error was in both versions that means it worked on 2.1.1 too. ERROR: FATAL datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to hadooptest3/<IP>:8020

Comment: You can add the logs and the config files in this question so that me or somebody else can answer you the right solution.